# My node chat application not show correct time in the client side but this is work great some browser Why?

Tags: javascript, express, socket.io, chat

I am jack junior web developer and I had some problems in my Node based chat application.
That is showing the time when the user sends their messages. You can see our code like this in my client-side Main.js file.

```
// Submit the form
  $('form').submit(async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let time = await getTime();
    socket.emit('brodcast', putUserMsg( $('#msg').val(), time));

    $('#msg').val('');
    return false;
  });

function getTime(){
  // For reference 
  // Create instance of Date and get the notation 
  // const notation = new Date().toLocaleString().split(' ')[2];

  //split the time zone
  // const timearr = new Date().toLocaleString().split(' ')[1].split(':');

  return `${
    new Date()
      .toLocaleString()
      .split(' ')[1]
      .split(':')[0]
  }:${
    new Date()
      .toLocaleString()
      .split(' ')[1]
      .split(':')[1]
  } ${new Date().toLocaleString().split(' ')[2]}`;
}

// Return object 
function putUserMsg(msg, time){
  return{
      msg,
      time
  }
}
```

[This is my mobile view in [chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqOMn.jpg) Browser and you can notice that when the message type and press enter the time was showed undefined why it's happened. But I am also trying a different browser like Ucbrower it works very well. Why did they happen? Similarly, On my [laptop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8IYtP.png), it's work very well my one and the only question is why they don't show in the Chrome browser?

Advance thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why it works on other browsers but doesn't work on Chrome, but let me give you a general advice: **Keep it as simple as possible.**

You're performing various manipulations on the Date object, which are hard to follow and debug. All you need to do, is just send the Date object as it is, which will be converted automatically to Date().toISOString(). This string, that looks something like *2020-04-02T23:51:13.866Z*, is the only thing you need to store. It's the universal UTC time, which is unaffected by your local area and day-light saving changes.

So your socketIO emition should look like that:

```
 socket.emit('brodcast', putUserMsg( $('#msg').val(), new Date()));
```

Later on, in your UI, You can make the desired manipulations on the Date, and present it as you wish. Once you receive the Date string(the one that was created automatically, when you sent the Date object before) back from the server, you can do something like this:

```
<p>{new Date(timeStringFromServer).toLocaleTimeString()}</p>//This will create a Date object from the string, and allow you to manipulate it.
```

But the thing you send through socket.io/ajax, should always be as simple as new Date().Also, i recommend using Moment.js for dates.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help yeah its work by changing the getTime() method and instead of this I am try the following bits line of code.```const time = new Date().toLocalString('en-US', { hour : 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', hour12 : true});   thats it! Again thank you!